# Html.ActionLink() Object parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How the third paramter of this method (`@Html.ActionLink(genre.Name,"Browse",new { genre = genre.Name })`) accepts `new { genre = genre.Name }`. It is of type System.Object. How it is possible to create whatever property name I want and to be assigned to this same property ?

Infact if I type this `object o = new object() { gnere = "2" };`. It is not valid. 
How it is possible to be valid in `@Html.ActionLink(genre.Name,"Browse",new { genre = genre.Name })` ?

Comment: You may want to read about [anonymous types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397696.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You're typing your syntax wrong here...

Try:

```
object o = new { genre = "2" };
```

This is down to the object being a dynamic object (its properties can be created at run-time). You can do the same using the dynamic object:

```
dynamic o = new { genre = "2" };
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492936%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) docs.

The third parameter is described as

> routeValues
>   Type: System.Object
>   An object that contains the parameters for a route. The parameters are retrieved through reflection by examining the properties of the object. The object is typically created by using object initializer syntax.

`routeValues` is used to provide details of the route. For example in your case you probably have an action method in your controller that expects a variable called `genre`. The underlying framework will translate your routevalue `genre` to this.

Answer (score 0):

actually new { genre = genre.Name } is not a System.Object object. But if we returns back to your question, you may use var type in this case:

```
var o = new { genre = "2" };
@Html.ActionLink(genre.Name,"Browse", o)
```